# Passing arguments when calling Webots with `createProcess()`

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file

I'm trying to lauch Webots from some C++ code I'm writing, but running into some issues. The version of Webots I am running is 7.4.3 (for some unrelated reasons I am unable to update to 8.1.0 at the time), which has a known bug when interpreting command-line parameters (https://www.cyberbotics.com/forum?message=5222).

I want to pass a specific file as an argument so that Webots opens it. It is default application in Windows for handling this type of files, such that if I just place the path to the file on the command line, or just click on it, it is opened by Webots. I'm using `createProcess()` to call webots from my C++ program, however, placing the path to the file instead of the program executable an error is thrown (as expected, since the file is not an executable).

Strangely, using the "Run" window (instead of cmd.exe) I can pass the arguments as supposed (http://www.cyberbotics.com/dvd/common/doc/webots/guide/section2.2.html).

It should be noted that the Webots instalation provides `webots.exe` and `webots.bat`, which I assume includes additional library paths in Windows since I get "missing [...].dll" if I attempt to run `webots.exe`

So I have two questions regarding this issue:

1) What exactly is the difference between the "Run" window and the Command Line, since they show different behaviours when calling the same command?

2) Would it be possible to use `createProcess()` to call the "Run" window and send the command to be run as an argument?

EDIT:

Relevant snippet of the code I'm compiling:

```
//[...]
LPTSTR cmdArgs="C:\\path\\to\\file":
STARTUPINFO info={sizeof(info)};
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;

if(CreateProcess("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Webots\\webots.bat", cmdArgs, 
    NULL,NULL,FALSE,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL,
    NULL,&StartupInfo,&ProcessInfo))
{ 
    WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
} else {
    printf("Unable to execute");
}
//[...]
```

This way, Webots opens but not the `cmdArgs` file, alternatively I get `Unable to execute` if I place `cmdArgs` as the first argument (`NULL` as the second) when calling `createProcess()` - the specific error I don't know, have to change the code to catch it.

EDIT 2:

Webots.bat:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set Path=%CD%\lib;%CD%\mingw\bin;%CD%\msys\bin;%Path%
start webots.exe
```

Comment: What's the exact error message? What are the arguments that you are passing to `CreateProcess`?

Comment: @CristiFati updated my question with the code

Answer (score 0):

It's what I thought. Here's `CreateProcess` [official doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)

Try this:

```
LPTSTR cmdArgs = TEXT("/c \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Webots\\webots.bat\" \"C:\\path\\to\\file\"");
// The other statements
if(CreateProcess(TEXT("cmd.exe"), cmdArgs, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL,
 NULL, &info, &processInfo))
// The rest of the statements
```

What has been done:

1. According to the link above, the first token in the `lpCommandLine` string is the program (app) name. It's like in `main`, `argc[0]` is the executable name. The exception is when running `.bat` files (this is exactly our case); then the `lpApplicationName` should be set to `cmd.exe`, and the `lpCommandLine` to `/c` followed by the batch name (and args).
2. According to the same doc, if the path names contain spaces (and in your case they do) they must be enclosed in `"`s.
3. I assume that there was a typo when pasting the code, otherwise it wouldn't compile. The last 2 arguments of `CreateProcess` were not correct (I replaced `&StratupInfo` by `&info` and `&ProcessInfo` by `&processInfo`).
4. The last thing that i did was enclosing any literal string in the program by the `TEXT` macro. This is required when writing programs that work with both *ASCII* and *WideChar* strings. Although it doesn't make any *visible* difference to your code because you don't have `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` macros defined, meaning that your program uses *ASCII* strings (hmm, I wonder why is that since by default *Visual Studio* defines them; unless you manually undefined them), but if you define (or better: un-undefine) them, you'll get a bunch of compilation errors that make no sense at first glance.

Comment: This does not solve my issue yet. This is what I assume is the correct way to call the .bat file, but the issue is still within the .bat file. I've opened it and it seems it only adds the program's directory to the PATH variable, the it executes, but arguments are lost in the process.

Comment: Ok then, maybe the `.bat` file content would be useful.

Comment: Updated my question. I'm not particulary familiar with batch files, but this seems like a rather simple one.

Comment: Change the last line to: `start webots.exe %*`

Comment: It did. I found out that the issue was also with the encoding of `C:\\file\\to\\path`, including some characters like "ã". I'll put together an answer detailing the solution.